# How to configure basic authentication in tomcat 8.5? HTTP Error 401

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to secure my web application in tomcat with `web.xml` and `tomcat-users.xml` but it's not working. I've getting 401 error with the correct login and password.

My `web.xml` security part:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Web Application</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>myuser</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
    <role-name>myuser</role-name>
</security-role>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

My `tomcat-users.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">

    <role rolename="myuser"/>
    <role username="myuser" password="myuser" role="myuser"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it missing the `http-methods`, so you can try adding this:

```
<http-method>GET</http-method>
<http-method>POST</http-method>
```

after of `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` tag

**UPDATE**

Update your `tomcat-users.xml` file, change this:

```
<role username="myuser" password="myuser" role="myuser"/>
```

for this:

```
<user username="myuser" password="myuser" role="myuser"/>
```

Comment: I already tried to do it, the result is the same. Only one change in logs: `For security constraints with URL pattern [/*] only the HTTP methods [POST GET] are covered. All other methods are uncovered.`

Comment: Try to update your `tomcat-users.xml` file, check the update entry

Comment: great! I'm glad I helped